# php files upload not working

Tags: php, html

I have a HTML page,where file input type is defined. but when i try uploading it, its not working using move function. then found that, echoing file name itself not printing anything after selecting any file...

**HTML:**

```
<form id="upload_items" name="upload_items" method="post" action="items.php">
  <input type="file" name="itemlist_file" id="itemlist_file" />
  <br />  <br />
  <input type="submit" name="Upload" value="Upload" id="Upload" />
  </form>
```

**Form submission php page:**

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
echo (basename($_FILES["itemlist_file"]["name"])
```

**Output:**

> Nothing displayed...

Comment: Is `Form submission page` the items.php file?

Comment: You must add `enctype='multipart/form-data'` to your forms attributes.

Comment: yes it is... i am wondering

Comment: @logan - That seems very strange. The only thing that seems incorrect is that you forgot to add this attribute.

Comment: i think enctype is main issue and you can also see full example file upload in php from here : http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: @Zword : I can accept the answer only after 15 mins. Its setup by stackover flow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add this to the form :-

```
enctype='multipart/form-data'
```

`enctype='multipart/form-data` is an encoding type that allows files to be sent through a POST. Quite simply, without this encoding the files cannot be sent through POST.

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to provide the correct enctype which is obligatory for uploads. Add the enctype attribute to your form like:

```
<form id="upload_items" name="upload_items method="post" action="items.php" enctype="multipart/form-data"> ...
```